# chrome css: border-radius not showing up

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm having a problem with border-radius on Chrome (latest build). I have a border-radius: 10px; on the slider frame from this page: http://next.lab501.ro/

In Firefox and IE9 everything works, but not on Chrome and I can't figure it out why, because I have other elements with border-radius that work just fine in Chrome.

Comment: which frame..??.. code?.. id of the frame.. any proper relevant info!!!

Comment: Yes, let's have the smallest sample of the code you've got that can reproduce the problem, please.

Comment: This is the slider wraper: 

    div.slidedeck_frame.skin-image_caption_top {
    position: relative;
    width: 992px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }

Comment: It's also not showing in Safari, so your problem is with webkit browsers in general. But there's quite a lot of code to wade through unless you can narrow it down for us by reproducing it with a smaller example. webkit doesn't have any general problems with border-radius, as far as I can remember... It may help to make your markup at least structurally valid ([47 validation errors at first glance](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnext.lab501.ro%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), some of them relating to document structure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked using Safari's "Web Inspector", and your CSS is definitely being successfully applied to your container.

I *think* the problem is related to the contained content of an element with border-radius "breaking out" over the container's rounded corners. See [this article](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/266/css-inner-elements-breaking-border-radius) for more background. I believe the problem was first properly reported by [Richard Rutter](http://clagnut.com/blog/2273/).

In your case, you are already using `overflow: hidden` on the container, and that's not working -- this may be related to the z-indexes you've got going, but it's hard to tell with such a complex example.

I would try rounding the corners of the contained elements that appear to be overflowing, though. This seems to work for me on that page:

```
dl.slidedeck {
    border-radius: 10px; 
}

div.sd-node.sd-node-caption {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```